# Using Radio Button for boolean field in Modelform

Tags: django

in models

```
choice = models.BooleanField()
```

in forms I use

```
choices = (
('1', 'Buy'),
('0', 'Sell'),
```

)

```
choice = forms.TypedChoiceField(label=u'Тип предожения', choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect,)
```

but when i edit item, value is not selected... How can I make to previous selected value be marked

Answer (score 1):

You've used strings for your choices keys. Booleans are `True` and `False`.